# Select nodes based on attribute value of a node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to report an xml file to a table in html. I selected correctly the nodes that i needed but i want to include in the table a set of nodes only if one node contains a certain value.
The table have to be created reporting each Station with Sensor and only the  Sector that are Active (to be Active the attribute name=Active needs to have value=1). So if it is Active, i need to report all the attributes in the nodes that are active, including the attributes left, right and name and not only active. If it is not Active (value = 0) it has to report only the id of the Sector.

Another further problem is to have a table with the Station id=1 in another column (at the right) and not at the bottom of the Station id=0.

To explain better i show below some code of what i have done until now.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "Xslprovastack.xsl"?> 

<map>
    <class type="Station" id="0">
        <attribute name="Name" value="Tom"/>
        <attribute name="Width" value="15000"/>
        <attribute name="Height" value="10000"/>
        <class type="Sensor" id="1">
            <attribute name="Name" value="Pressure"/>
            <attribute name="Position" value="222"/>
        </class>
        <class type="Sector" id="0">
            <attribute name="Left" value="100"/>
            <attribute name="Right" value="1000"/>
            <attribute name="Active" value="1"/>
            <attribute name="Name" value="Begin"/>
        </class>
        <class type="Sector" id="1">
            <attribute name="Left" value="5000"/>
            <attribute name="Right" value="5500"/>
            <attribute name="Active" value="0"/>
            <attribute name="Name" value="End"/>
        </class>
    </class>
    <class type="Station" id="1">
        <attribute name="Name" value="Mark"/>
        <attribute name="Width" value="12500"/>
        <attribute name="Height" value="20000"/>
        <class type="Sensor" id="1">
            <attribute name="Name" value="Pressure"/>
            <attribute name="Position" value="420"/>
        </class>
        <class type="Sector" id="0">
            <attribute name="Left" value="200"/>
            <attribute name="Right" value="2000"/>
            <attribute name="Active" value="0"/>
            <attribute name="Name" value="Begin"/>
        </class>
        <class type="Sector" id="1">
            <attribute name="Left" value="15000"/>
            <attribute name="Right" value="15500"/>
            <attribute name="Active" value="1"/>
            <attribute name="Name" value="End"/>
        </class>
    </class>
</map>
```

using the xsl:

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  

  <xsl:template match = "/"> 
    <html>
      <style>
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        }
      </style>
      <body>
        <h2>Item</h2>
        <table>
          <!--xsl:apply-templates/> -->
          <tr bgcolor = "#9acd32">
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="map"/>
        </table>
      </body> 
    </html> 
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="map">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="class"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="class">
    <tr bgcolor = "#ff0000">
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@type"/> </td> 
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@id+1"/> </td> 
      <td></td> 
      <td></td> 
    </tr> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="Sensortype"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="Sectortype"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="attribute">
    <tr>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td> 
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
    </tr>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Sensortype">
    <xsl:for-each select="class"> 
     <xsl:if test="@type = 'Sensor'">
      <tr bgcolor = "#ffff00">
        <td> Sensor: <xsl:value-of select="@type"/> </td>
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="@id+1"/> </td>
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
      </tr> 
      <xsl:call-template name="sensorname"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sensorname">
  <xsl:for-each select="attribute"> 
    <tr>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td> 
      <td> Sensor: <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Sectortype">
  <xsl:for-each select="class"> 
   <xsl:if test="@type = 'Sector'">
    <tr bgcolor = "#00ffff">
      <td> Sector: <xsl:value-of select="@type"/> </td>
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@id+1"/> </td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td> 
    </tr>
    <xsl:call-template name="Sectorname"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Sectorname">
  <xsl:for-each select="attribute">
    <xsl:if test="@name = 'Active' and @value = 1">
      <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <tr>
          <td></td> 
          <td></td> 
          <td> Sector: <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
          <td> <xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>    
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the actual result:

```html
<html>
   <style>
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        }
      </style>
   <body>
      <h2>Item</h2>
      <table>
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#ff0000">
            <td>Station</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Tom</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Width</td>
            <td>15000</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Height</td>
            <td>10000</td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#ffff00">
            <td> Sensor: Sensor</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sensor: Name</td>
            <td>Pressure</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sensor: Position</td>
            <td>222</td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#00ffff">
            <td> Sector: Sector</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sector: Active</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#00ffff">
            <td> Sector: Sector</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#ff0000">
            <td>Station</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Width</td>
            <td>12500</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Height</td>
            <td>20000</td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#ffff00">
            <td> Sensor: Sensor</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sensor: Name</td>
            <td>Pressure</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sensor: Position</td>
            <td>420</td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#00ffff">
            <td> Sector: Sector</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#00ffff">
            <td> Sector: Sector</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sector: Active</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here with the xsl:if i can obtain only the row with the active value and not the other attributes of the same nodes. This is the expected output:

```html
<html>
   <style>
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        }
      </style>
   <body>
      <h2>Item</h2>
      <table>
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#ff0000">
            <td>Station</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Tom</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Width</td>
            <td>15000</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Height</td>
            <td>10000</td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#ffff00">
            <td> Sensor: Sensor</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sensor: Name</td>
            <td>Pressure</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sensor: Position</td>
            <td>222</td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#00ffff">
            <td> Sector: Sector</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sector: Left</td>
            <td>100</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sector: Right</td>
            <td>1000</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sector: Active</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sector: Name</td>
            <td>Begin</td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#00ffff">
            <td> Sector: Sector</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#ff0000">
            <td>Station</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Width</td>
            <td>12500</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Height</td>
            <td>20000</td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#ffff00">
            <td> Sensor: Sensor</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sensor: Name</td>
            <td>Pressure</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sensor: Position</td>
            <td>420</td>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#00ffff">
            <td> Sector: Sector</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#00ffff">
            <td> Sector: Sector</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sector: Left</td>
            <td>15000</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sector: Right</td>
            <td>15500</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sector: Active</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td> Sector: Name</td>
            <td>End</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

How should i select correctly all the attributes of the Active Sector?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main fix would be to move the check on the "Active" attribute into the template named "Sectortype"

```
<xsl:template name="Sectortype">
  <xsl:for-each select="class[@type = 'Sector']"> 
    <tr bgcolor = "#00ffff">
      <td> Sector: <xsl:value-of select="@type"/> </td>
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@id+1"/> </td>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td> 
    </tr>
    <xsl:if test="attribute[@name='Active']/@value='1'">
      <xsl:call-template name="Sectorname"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Note how the test on the `type` attribute can become part of the `xsl:for-each` rather than have a separate `xsl:if` statement.

Then, the "Sectorname" template would look like this

```
<xsl:template name="Sectorname">
  <xsl:for-each select="attribute">
    <tr>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td> 
      <td> Sector: <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I would consider simplifying the XSLT, as you have three similar templates that output `attribute` elements, that could combined into one by means of a parameter.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
  <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match = "/"> 
    <html>
      <style>
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        }
      </style>
      <body>
        <h2>Item</h2>
        <table>
          <!--xsl:apply-templates/> -->
          <tr bgcolor = "#9acd32">
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="map"/>
        </table>
      </body> 
    </html> 
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="class">
    <tr bgcolor = "#ff0000">
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@type"/> </td> 
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@id+1"/> </td> 
      <td></td> 
      <td></td> 
    </tr> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="Sensortype"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="Sectortype"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="attribute">
    <xsl:param name="prefix" />
    <tr>
      <td></td> 
      <td></td> 
      <td> 
        <xsl:if test="$prefix">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, ': ')" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </td>
      <td> 
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Sensortype">
    <xsl:for-each select="class[@type = 'Sensor']"> 
      <tr bgcolor = "#ffff00">
        <td> Sensor: <xsl:value-of select="@type"/> </td>
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="@id+1"/> </td>
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
      </tr> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute">
        <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="'Sensor'" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Sectortype">
    <xsl:for-each select="class[@type = 'Sector']"> 
      <tr bgcolor = "#00ffff">
        <td> Sector: <xsl:value-of select="@type"/> </td>
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="@id+1"/> </td>
        <td></td> 
        <td></td> 
      </tr>
      <xsl:if test="attribute[@name='Active']/@value='1'">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute">
          <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="'Sector'" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note the template matching "map" was not really necessary in this case, as XSLT's built-in templates would handle this.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly! Another question: how can i obtain a table with each station with its parameters in a different column, instead of this solution with the station 1 following the station 0 in the same column?

Comment: That may be tricky, to be honest. At least, too tricky to explain in comments, so you might want to ask a whole new question. Thanks!